# Utf "\x94" validation error in html/xhtml form for php

Tags: php, html, validation

Okay XHTML want's to play some games with me, I was doing fine, until up to now.
Looking at the two code snippets below I don't see anything wrong with them, 
however when I try to validate I get "The error was: utf8 "\x94" does not map to  Unicode 
on line 91, I have commented line 91 to denote the problem area.
And what's up with "Sorry this document could not be checked?

Is there something I am not seeing, cause I have been using the same Doctype and validating 
okay up until now?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

[alt text http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/3199/wtfe.png](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/3199/wtfe.png)

```
<option value=”29”>29</option>
<option value=”30”>30</option>
<!-- Here is line 91, below, there is nothing wrong with it? -->
<option value =”31”>31</option> <!-- Line 91 WTF? I still can't validate-->
</select>
<input type = "text" name = "year"
value = "YYYY" size = "4" /> </p>
<!-- This approach gives you more control for validating and formatting the information submitted. How?
Well the user will be given a preloaded Date of Brith box with the option to select the Month, Day and Year
as opposed to having the user type in some weird or crazy stuff.
The caveat though is the fact that the html code just becomes longer and cumbersome on the eyes or coder.-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably have some kind of "smart quotes" in your file. Replace them with normal ASCII quotes.

Comment: Smart quotes? Normal ASCII quotes? Okay, just Googled, thanks will give this a try, and I was having so much fun until the Validation train derailed :-(.

Comment: I got it fixed, it was not the Smart quotes, but based on your information I just re-coded the html form, I don't now if it's just me, but if you look at the code I posted, for value="30" to "29" the quotes seem inverted, I have no idea how that  happened, but  i just copied code from a working section from the html form and re-did the non working section, it validates and I can check user inputs, sweet, back to the php code cave.